# C# deadlock on cancel-operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

I am trying to make a cancel-method which ensures that the Task has gracefully stopped by blocking the caller until it is.

I am running into a deadlock for some reason, I think it is because the `cancel.Set()` happens before `cancel.WaitOne()`, which will then wait for *another* `cancel.Set()`, which isn't coming.

I would like to know how to resolve this deadlock.

This is the actual code, stripped of the business logic:

```
    ManualResetEvent cancel = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    Queue<string> queue;
    bool run;
    public void Start()
    {
        run = true;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Work);
    }
    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (!run)
        {
            return;
        }
        cancel.Reset();
        run = false;
        Requests.Clear();
        if (queue != null)
            queue.Clear();
        cancel.WaitOne();
    }
    private void Work(object state)
    {
        //fill queue depending on requests

        while (queue.Any() && Requests.Any() && run)
        {
            //fill queue some more recursively
            //remove requests as they are processed
        }
        //BUG: Deadlock
        cancel.Set();
    }
```

As you see, it's pretty much what I posted earlier. (either that or I am blind)

**UPDATE**

I wound up using a Task like this:

```
    Task activeItem;
    bool run;
    public void Start()
    {
        if(run)
            return;
        run = true;
        activeItem = Task.Factory.StartNew(Work);
    }
    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (!run)
        {
            return;
        }
        run = false;
        Requests.Clear();
        if (queue != null)
            queue.Clear();
        activeItem.Wait(500);
    }
    private void Work()
    {
        //fill queue depending on requests

        while (queue.Any() && Requests.Any() && run)
        {
            //fill queue some more recursively
            //remove requests as they are processed
        }
    }
```

by adding the timeout to the Task I found one really strange behaviour: The whole Cancel-Method seems to be blocking the Work()-Thread/Task as a whole. Only after Cancel() is finished will the Work()-Thread continue. Cancel is invoked through the UI Thread, how can this be?

Comment: I suspect that your diagnosis is incorrect.  The MRE maintains state and you call Reset before RequestCancel and then wait - that should be fine.  Are you, by any chance, calling Cancel() from a GUI event-handler?

Comment: There is very little hope this will work.  Calling Reset() will clear the Set() in the worker, deadlock city.  At least get ahead by calling Reset() before you start the tp thread.

Comment: @HansPassant - the worker will not call Set() until RequestCancel() is called first?

Comment: The worker will call `Set()` when he has finished cancelling and is about to end running, so definitely after `RequestCancel()`. Yes I am calling it from the GUI thread, the short amount of blocking until the worker is finished is okay though. (shouldn't be noticable actually, but leaving the thread unattended could lead to exceptions) @Hans: if the worker is not running cancel will not do anything. Editing to clarify.

Comment: @manuFS: The code you posted does not compile. If you edit your answer and fix it I will upvote.

Comment: Once you implement a Work function it will compile. Dumbest thing I've read today, sorry.

Comment: @manuFS: No, it doesn't. I know I'm being pedantic, but it's more than just implementing `Work`. The most important being that MRE does not have a parameterless constructor. I am now forced to *assume* which value you are actually passing in. Which, albeit, is probably moot in this case, but as with many threading issues the devil is in the details. And to be perfectly clear I was not your downvote.

Comment: @manuFS: Based on your comment to my answer I infer that the code you posted is not 100% representative of what you actually have. That's fine, just post more information about what is going on. What thread is calling `Start` and `Cancel`? That kind of thing. Though, posting code that is as close to possible to what you actually have is preferable.

Comment: Posted my actual code, stripped off the business logic.

Comment: run/isBusy should be volatile.  Are you not using .NET 4.0?  If you are you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, consider BlockingCollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) and Tasks.

Comment: I am just learning now, but from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx. Maybee you got the set and waitone wrong. As a deadlock makes your thread block themselves..? :)

Comment: @MarkSowul I tried volatile, it didn't change anything in my case.

Comment: @manuFS: I have to be honest. I'm not seeing anything overtly wrong with your code that would cause it to deadlock. Try commenting out your business logic in small chunks until it stops deadlock (or the opposite, start with this and add stuff back in until it starts deadlocking) and see if that helps narrow down the issue.

Comment: I fear it might be some databinding-magic happening here. I bet if I'd take the stripped code and run it in a naked project it will work. I'll try that later. Thanks for looking at it, anyways.

Comment: @manuFS I should have been clear that while it's not the cause of your problem but it is an additional problem; the larger point is whether to roll your own version of this when there are abstractions available.  Anyway, are you using Invoke() or the like?